# Как активировать intel software manager в Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Мне нужно в своем проекте включить опции как на скрине (это с мануала скрин)

[image]

Проблема в том, что когда я открываю Properties своего проета у меня нет этой вкладки `Inter Performance Lib`

Согласно этой статьи

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/installing-microsoft-visual-studio-2019-for-use-with-intel-compilers.html

Нужно проверить, что поддержка C++ включена (у меня включена) и так же я вижу, что там отмечен еще этот чекбокс `Intel Core`

У меня его тоже нет. Так же я вижу, что есть вот такие настройки (которых у меня тоже нет)

[image]

В общем впечатление, что либо я что то недоустановил либо мой Intel просто этого не поддерживает

Вопрос - что делаю не так?